# How to avoid 'Font shape undefined' problems when checking an R package?

Tags: r, latex, devtools, rtools

I am trying to publish my first R package. I run the `R CMD CHECK` command and managed to clear all warnings and notes except the one saying:

> LaTeX errors when creating PDF version. This typically indicates Rd
> problems.

I checked the LaTex log file but I can't make any sense of any of the information in there.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Here is the file:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

   
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmtt/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OML/cmm/m/it' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textless' on input line 20.

 
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on Rd2.pdf (4 pages, 117453 bytes).
Transcript written on Rd2.log.
Saving output to '<package-manual>.pdf' ...
Done
```

Comment: The latex log does not look too bad, a couple of warnings, but I can't find any error message.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes it's actually one warning only. Nonetheless, I can't submit my package to CRAN unless I find a way to silence that. The warning is question is: `Font shape OML/cmtt/m/n' undefined; using OML/cmm/m/it instead`.
I believe you can help me with that?

Comment: without seeing a [mre] to reproduce the warning, the most we can say is: use a font which has the shapes you use.

Comment: .... but I highly doubt solving the warning will solve the problem. Why would any sane program interpret the warning as error? There must be something else going on

Comment: The checking of submitted R packages on CRAN is an automated process. If the process triggers any warning or even "notes", then the application won't go through. In my case, the PDF documentation is generated and if it wasn't for this warning, then everything could have been fine.